# Render overridden fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news, typo3-11.x

I want to override an extension's fluid template in Typo3 with my own template. My own template contains an if-condition. If not met, I want to include/render the extension's template (i.e. the overridden template) instead.

The actual case: I'm using the Typo3 News Extension which allows custom "[template layouts](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/10.0/en-us/Tutorials/Templates/TemplateSelector/Index.html)". I want to add my custom template layout but also keep the News Extension's default template:

```html
<!-- my_site_package/Resources/Private/Extensions/News/Templates/News/List.html -->
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 2">
  
  <f:then>
    My specific list view for news entries
    <ul>
      <li>
        ...
      </li>
    </ul>
  </f:then>
  
  <f:else>
    <!--
      Include the original template here, e.g.
       EXT:news/Resources/Private/Templates/Styles/Twb5/Templates/News/List.html
     -->
  </f:else>
  
</f:if>
```

How can I include / render the overridden template itself?

Comment: Not clear what's your question here...

Comment: If templateLayout != 2 I want to use the original template provided by the extension. My current workaround is to copy the original List.html content to where comment "Include ..." is in the code above.

Comment: And it's working? Are there errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluid Is not able to Render the "Original Template" as there might be any number of TemplateRootpaths providing the Template. what you could do:

if the original Template is Part of an extension you controll, best to move the "Repeating" parts to an Partial. and let the Original Template use this partial as well.

if the original template is part of an extension you do not controll. (eg by a third party) you should copy the orignal template as partial in your Extension and then render this Partial. maybe ad a comment that this is an 1:1 copy of the original and shoud not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another template layouts using page TSConfig, Define this TS in your root Page TSconfig (inside Resources) Tab.

```
plugin.tx_news {
  templateLayouts {
    1 = Homepage
    2 = Specific list
  }
}
```

then in your template you will get selected template value here in case 1 or 2.

You will find more help here.
https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Reference/TsConfig/General.html#confval-templateLayouts

Comment: Yes that it is what I'm referring to in my question. How does this answer the question?

Comment: @fishbone Not getting your question, can you please elaborate in detail?